# Using link_to with delete action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my grid this,

```
link_to('Edit', edit_manage_user_path(user.id))
```

works fine but this,

```
link_to('Delete', delete_manage_user_path(user.id))
```

gives the error "undefined method `delete_manage_user_path' for #<#:0xc05439c>" given that there is a delete action in my controller..

Any idea why this error is coming?

Comment: You can add `method: :delete` to the `link_to`. Together with that, you can add a confirm step since the deletion isn't reverted, hence the code looks like `link_to 'Delete', manage_user_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure to delete?" }` .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use `resources` routes, path to `destroy` action is the same as to `show`, but you should use HTTP `DELETE` method:

```
link_to 'Delete', [:manage, user], method: :delete
```

Answer (score 20):

#### Before Rails 7

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', manage_user_path(user),
  method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
```

#### Rails 7 (with Turbo, out of the box)

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', manage_user_path(user),
  data: {turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

Comment: Source: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#deleting-an-article

Answer (score 3):

```
 link_to 'Delete', manage_user_path(user), method: :delete
```

This will call your delete action. there is no such path `delete_manage_user_path(user)` if you are using restful routing.

Comment: this worked for me, but it was looking for a destroy method in the controller, and after change def delete to def destroy, its working perfectly in Rails 5.2.

Answer (score 2):

I always prefered the button way:

```
 = form_with url: destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete do |form|
   = form.submit "Sign out"
```

Comment: This form button way works for me, while the link constructed with `method: :delete` in the above example never hits the `:destroy` action. Why is that?

Comment: The "link" version requires some JS rails libraries. Many people remove them, thinking they are not necessary.

Comment: Ahaa... thank you, yes i found the libraries. It requires both `jquery` and `jquery_ujs` to make these links work.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing is half the battle. You'll need to figure out which is the correct route for deleting your resource. You can do so by running the following command:

`bundle exec rake routes`

Here's an example of the output from one of my own Rails apps:
[image]

I added an arrow to what you should be looking for.

Once you have the route, you'll then need to specify how you want to send the HTTP request when the user clicks on the link. You can do this by supplying the `method` key in nested the custom `data` attributes. Here's an example:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", user_path(user), data: { method: :delete } %>
```

Additional Resources:

- [UrlHelper#link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) docs

Answer (score 0):

The format for the delete call is:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', manage_user_path(user.id), :method => :delete %>
```

use `rake routes` to learn about the available routes, including generated route helpers, and the controller/action handling the request.